# Display content from Github pages inside an Angular Page

Tags: .net, angular, github, documentation

I am trying to build a knowledge base for my website. I looked around for options and found out that Microsoft is doing something interesting, such that documentation can be easily updated by anyone. They are storing their documentation in git hub repo and having that content somehow display in their web page.

Ex: Here's a link to their Getting Started Page. If you click on edit, it goes the exact GitHub page where the documentation is present.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/get-started

My application is angular based, and I would read and display this content from Github in my application. I am wondering if anyone can share an example or an angular plugin that allows me to do this. Is there an HTML generation script involved that generates HTML from the *.md pages?

Comment: They are likely using either the GitHub API (https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get the contents, or using a automated build (more likely) solution.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Python, where we can iterate through the git repo and generate HTML files from .md files? The HTML files can then be consumed in the Angular UI

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the page the 'Edit' button goes to is a markdown page, which is what READMEs are written in, generally. Luckily, its a form of markup like HTML so you can use something like [ngx-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown) to parse the markdown. Further, to import a file from a github repo, just have it as regular file and then commit it as normal.

Good luck!